# ERC20Mintable contract call return wrong number

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I use OpenZeppilin ERC20Mintable contract and add `MaxSupply` parameter to contraint the ERC20 token amount allowed to issue.

what I want is only permit contract ower to view `MaxSupply` info, my function is below:

```
uint256 MaxSupply;//contract static variable
...
// self defined function
function ViewMaxSupply() public view onlyMinter return(uint256) {
 return ( MaxSupply* (10 ** uint256(decimals)) );
}
```

`decimals` is equal to `18`.

I found when I use `onlyMiner` modifier, the return value is a very strange number: `3963877391197344453575983046348115674221700746820753546331534351508065746944`.
when not use modifier `onlyMinter`, the result is correct: `100000000000000000000`

How to fix the error?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you invoke `ViewMaxSupply`? Since it is a view function it doesn't use from so it might be failing and the call doesn't detect it as an invalid answer.

Comment: Perhaps submit as an issue on Github? Make sure to mention your Solidity version.

Comment: @Ismael , I call it by `var MaxIssueAmount = await contract.methods.ViewMaxSupply().call();`

Comment: @Ivan P  OK, my solidity version is `>npm ls solc  solc@0.5.9 `, the compiler version in .sol file(`pragma solidity ^0.5.0`) is lower, I make no modification.

Comment: @Ntydrm Try passing a minter address as from parameter, like this `var MaxIssueAmount = await contract.methods.ViewMaxSupply().call({ from: "0xVALID_ADDRESS" })`.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the OpenZeppelin Community Forum
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/erc20mintable-contract-application-returns-a-strange-wrong-number/1178/2

---

To have a mintable token with a capped (maximum) supply you can use OpenZeppelin ERC20Capped https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20Capped

Adding a modifier to view the MaxSupply only prevents other contracts from reading the value, but it is visible externally.

> https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=private#visibility-and-getters 
>   Everything that is inside a contract is visible to all observers external to the blockchain. Making something private only prevents other contracts from reading or modifying the information, but it will still be visible to the whole world outside of the blockchain.

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin